# Excel dates not formatting correctly

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Thank you for reading this question and the attempt you will put into this to help me,appreciate it.

Anyways, i have an excel file that i am trying to get into SQL via import. Everything works fine but when I check excel i see some rows as null where there should be values. (btw my date format in SQL is mdy). So I checked in excel and saw that the dates were a little different so i selected the column and formatted them the same. However i still noticed the same error. Upon further investigation I realize the dates are still different in the fomular bar and the dates formatted as '30-sept-93 (with the little green mark in the corner) come over correctly while those that look like 5/7/1993.

I was wondering if there was some way or macro that i can change all those dates to ACTUALLY be like this correct rather than just looking right and breaking in SQL
[image: Correct results vs wrong one]

Comment: Formatting will indeed only change the appearance of your data, not change the actual input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `=DATEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"DD-MMM-YYYY"))` function on that column.